# Convert time (HH:MM:SS) to minutes in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, datetime

How to convert HH:MM:SS to Minutes?

I tried below works fine:

```
  import datetime as DT
  t1 = DT.datetime.strptime('0:10:00', '%H:%M:%S')
```

I tried another example and getting error:

```
  import datetime as DT
  t1 = DT.datetime.strptime('9715:56:46', '%H:%M:%S')
```

Error:

```
  ValueError: time data '9715:56:46' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

In this example it support Max 23 for %H, If my hours has more than 23(in this case i have 9715 hours) how to get it?

Comment: Error is self-explanatory your hour components are invalid values, it should be `00` for the first example and since when is `9715` a valid hour? What time are you expecting from the last example?

Comment: Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23]. Here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Comment: From `help(time.strptime)`: "*%H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23].*".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `sum` with a generator expression or `map`:

```
from operator import mul

my_time = '9715:56:46'
factors = (60, 1, 1/60)

t1 = sum(i*j for i, j in zip(map(int, my_time.split(':')), factors))
t2 = sum(map(mul, map(int, my_time.split(':')), factors))

print(t1)  # 582956.7666666667

assert t1 == t2
```

Answer (score 9):

`datetime.datetime` is a representation of a point in time, not a duration of time.

`datetime.timedelta` is a representation of a length of time.  Observe:

```
from datetime import timedelta


delta = timedelta(hours=9715, minutes=56, seconds=46)
total_seconds = delta.total_seconds()
minutes = int(total_seconds // 60)
seconds = int(total_seconds % 60)

print('{minutes}:{seconds}'.format(minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds))
```

EDIT:  I changed the code to work with python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

The `strptime` function (in its various incarnations) isn't designed to perform this sort of task, it's just for parsing valid time / date strings.

The simple solution is to write your own code to parse the string and perform the arithmetic. Here's an example that outputs seconds; obviously you can divide by 60 to get minutes.

```
def hms_to_s(s):
    t = 0
    for u in s.split(':'):
        t = 60 * t + int(u)
    return t

data = (
    '10',
    '0:10',
    '1:30',
    '2:1:00',
    '1000:00:00',
    '9700:00:00',
    '15:56:46',
    '9715:56:46',
)

for s in data:
    print(s, hms_to_s(s))
```

**output**

```
10 10
0:10 10
1:30 90
2:1:00 7260
1000:00:00 3600000
9700:00:00 34920000
15:56:46 57406
9715:56:46 34977406
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you have provided wrong value for the hour.

It must be >=0 and < 24.

[https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html][1]

For converting into minutes:

```
input_time='9715:56:46'
t=input_time.split(':')

total_minutes= int(t[0])*60+int(t[1])*1 +int(t[2])/60
```

Answer (score 1):

simple one that supports d:h:m:s / h:m:s / m:s / s !

```
def dhms_to_sec(dhms_str):
    '''supports also format of d:h:m:s, h:m:s, m:s and s'''
    _,d,h,m,s = (':0'*10+dhms_str).rsplit(':',4)
    return int(d)*24*60*60+int(h)*60*60+int(m)*60+int(s) 

# examples:
print(dhms_to_sec('04'))  # will print 4
print(dhms_to_sec('1:04'))  # will print 64
print(dhms_to_sec('1:01:04'))  # will print 3664
print(dhms_to_sec('1:1:4'))  # will print 3664
```

you can convert it to minutes by /60 ... 
it will accept also weird cases like 1:56:0

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad concept of the library and how it works, look, the firs parameter is the hour of the day in the forma 00-23, for example 22 is the 10 pm, so valid hours goes from range 00 to 23, another input is an invalid input.

example:

```
import datetime as DT
t1 = DT.datetime.strptime('23:56:46', '%H:%M:%S')
```

Observation:

The first value can be `0` or `00` , but `000` also will produce the same error:

```
t1 = DT.datetime.strptime('0:56:46', '%H:%M:%S') # it's ok
t1 = DT.datetime.strptime('00:56:46', '%H:%M:%S') # it's ok
t1 = DT.datetime.strptime('000:56:46', '%H:%M:%S') # same error you got
```

Comment: For formats like `t1 = DT.datetime.strptime('0:56:46', '%H:%M:%S')` you should be careful if you ever have values that are not fixed-length, since there can be ambiguous behavior when processing it. e.g., if you remove the first colon, the time changes to 5:06 am instead of 12:06 am. In some cases, the parser won't work because it's not in POSIXct format.

In general I use regexes to fix potential ambiguities or formats that don't work with the `datetime` module.

Comment: @MaxCandocia that's an excellent observation I didn't know that, thanks a lot for share it !

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to convert the string "01:21:48" to minutes.

```
from datetime import timedelta

h = "01:21:48"
delta = timedelta(hours=int(h.split(':')[0]), minutes=int(h.split(':')[1]), seconds=int(h.split(':')[2]))
minutes = delta.total_seconds()/60
print(minutes)
```

So the printed result is: 81.8

Answer (score 0):

```
i = "15:21"
sp = i.split(":")
minutes = 0.0
if len(sp) == 3:
    minutes = minutes + int(sp[0]) * 60
    minutes = minutes + int(sp[1])
    minutes = minutes + int(sp[2]) / 60
elif len(sp) == 2:
    minutes = minutes + int(sp[0])
    minutes = minutes + int(sp[1]) / 60
elif len(sp) == 1:
    minutes = minutes + int(sp[0]) / 60
print(minutes)
```

A Good solution :)