# how do I convert hh:mm:ss (0:1:19) to minutes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to convert the following data into minute, but i always land up on error

```
time = 0:1:19

time1 = df['time']

time2 = time1.hour * 60 + time1.minute + time1.second
```

I get this error:

```
 "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'"
```

Comment: your first command `time = 0:1:19` is not a valid python command, at least python3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a datetime format to minutes - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392796/how-to-convert-a-datetime-format-to-minutes-pandas)

Comment: Syntax aside, the number of minutes is hours*60 + minutes + seconds/60.

Comment: Also you could have a look at this: [convert time hh:mm:ss to minutes -python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447123/convert-time-hhmmss-to-minutes-in-python/48447482)

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.to_timedelta` to covnert time to `timedelta` to get seconds.

```
time1 = pd.Series(['0:1:19', '1:01:19', '0:0:19'])
obj = pd.to_timedelta(time1)
# convert to minutes
obj.dt.seconds / 60.0

    0     1.316667
    1    61.316667
    2     0.316667
    dtype: float64
```